# Optimizing AJAX Query with Large Database

Tags: wp-query, ajax, database, query

I have a WordPress AJAX function that performs a location-based search on a website with a large database of over 100,000 posts... The function is responsible for querying the database to find the count of posts that match specific criteria for each location provided via the AJAX request.
This execute with autocomplete input if (value.length >= 3) to avoid many requests.

Here's an excerpt of the code:

```
public function custom_request()
{
    check_ajax_referer('data_seg', 'nonce'); // Validate nonce
    extract($_POST, EXTR_OVERWRITE);

    switch ($modelo) {
        case 'search_location':
            if (is_array($location) && isset($operacion) && isset($tipo)) {
                $results = [];
                foreach ($location as $locationValue) {
                    $args = [
                        'post_type' => 'properties',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'fields' => 'ids',
                        'posts_per_page' => 1,
                        'meta_query' => [
                            [
                                'key' => $locationValue['model'],
                                'value' => $locationValue['label'],
                            ],
                        ],
                        'tax_query' => [
                            'relation' => 'AND',
                            [
                                'taxonomy' => 'es_category',
                                'field' => 'term_id',
                                'terms' => $operacion,
                                'operator' => 'AND',
                            ],
                            [
                                'taxonomy' => 'es_type',
                                'field' => 'term_id',
                                'terms' => $tipo,
                                'operator' => 'AND',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ];
                    $query = new WP_Query($args);
                    $querycount = $query->found_posts;
                    $results[$locationValue['label']] = $querycount;
                }

                // Now $results contains the label and the number of associated posts for each label
                echo json_encode([
                    'success' => true,
                    'data' => $results,
                    'message' => 'Successful query',
                ]);
            } else {
                echo json_encode([
                    'success' => false,
                    'data' => [],
                    'message' => 'Missing data to execute the query',
                ]);

              
            }

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    wp_die();
}
```

I'm looking for suggestions on how to optimize this code, especially when dealing with a large database. Are there any best practices or performance enhancements that can be applied to improve the speed and efficiency of this AJAX query?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!